# Reusable animations

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am a complete newbie to WPF and XAML.

I have created a simple fade-in and fade-out animation for a textbox:-

```
<Storyboard x:Key="storyFadeInOutTop" Name="storyFadeInOutTop">
    <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1" Duration="00:00:01" 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="txtTopCredit" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
    </DoubleAnimation>
    <DoubleAnimation From="10" To="0" Duration="00:00:01" BeginTime="00:00:01"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="blurTop" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Radius">
    </DoubleAnimation>
    <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="10" Duration="00:00:01" BeginTime="00:00:05"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="blurTop" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Radius">
    </DoubleAnimation>
    <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0" Duration="00:00:01" BeginTime="00:00:06"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="txtTopCredit" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
    </DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

What I would like to do is run this storyboard several times within the lifecyle of the animation.

Something like:-

```
<Storyboard>
   <!-- (Run my fade-in-fade out with BeginTime of 00:00:00) -->
   <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:01" BeginTime="00:00:07"
           Storyboard.TargetName="txtTopCredit" 
           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text">
          <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Game design and concept by" KeyTime="0:0:1" />
    </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
   <!-- (Run my fade-in-fade out again with BeginTime of 00:00:07) -->
   <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:01" BeginTime="00:00:07"
           Storyboard.TargetName="txtTopCredit" 
           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text">
          <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Look Ive changed to another credit" KeyTime="0:0:1" />
    </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <!-- (etc etc) -->
</Storyboard>
```

I hope you understand the gist of what I'm trying to do. I know I could just add the code in the storyboard to each section of the above but that would be very tedious. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Note: O.K. So I did a little digging and used code to start and stop the storyboards, along with event handlers to control sequencing of when they run. It would be nice to know if there was a way to do this in pure XAML though.

Comment: I think you are better off managing these animations with code (unfortunately).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the `RepeatBehavior` property on the storyboard [(inherited from Timeline)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.repeatbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<Storyboard x:Key="storyFadeInOutTop" Name="storyFadeInOutTop" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
    <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1" Duration="00:00:01" 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="txtTopCredit" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
    </DoubleAnimation>
    <DoubleAnimation From="10" To="0" Duration="00:00:01" BeginTime="00:00:01"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="blurTop" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Radius">
    </DoubleAnimation>
    <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="10" Duration="00:00:01" BeginTime="00:00:05"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="blurTop" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Radius">
    </DoubleAnimation>
    <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0" Duration="00:00:01" BeginTime="00:00:06"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="txtTopCredit" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
    </DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

`RepeatBehavior` can also be set to a positive integer.